# Unity3D Drag Object with Mouse Gives Invalid Position

Tags: c#, unity, mouse, transformation

I am trying to implement a simple script to drag a GameObject with the mouse in Unity.
However, when the position of the object is updated with the following script, I get an error saying:

```
transform.position assign attempt for 'purpie_5' is not valid. Input position is { Infinity, 51351759646418134000000000000000.000000, -143589927261340110000000000000000000000.000000 }.
UnityEngine.Transform:set_position(Vector3)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This is the code I am using:

```
public class MouseInputInterface : MonoBehaviour {

#region PUBLIC MEMBERS
public Transform heldObject;
#endregion //PUBLIC MEMBERS

#region PRIVATE MEMBERS
private GameObject currTarget;
private Vector3 touchOffset;
private bool dragging = false;
#endregion //PRIVATE MEMBERS


// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{

}

    void Update()
    {
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out rHit))
        {

            currTarget = rHit.transform.gameObject;


            if(currTarget != null)
            {
                if(!dragging && currTarget.transform.tag == "Moveable")
                {
                    dragging = true;
                    heldObject = currTarget.transform;
                }

            }

        }

        if(heldObject != null)
        {
            /*calculate offset*/
            Vector3 screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(heldObject.position);

            /*calculate offset from camera*/
            Vector3 offset = heldObject.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));

            //form the current position
            Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint) + offset;

            heldObject.transform.position = curPosition;
        }
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        //clear held object
        heldObject = null;
        //clear flag
        dragging = false;
    }

    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line where you get the world position of the mouse:

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(
    new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
```

The z value should be the difference from the camera to the object. For example, with a camera looking "down" the Y axis:

```
public Vector3 GetMousePositionInWorld(Transform heldObject) {
    Vector3 clickPos = Input.mousePosition;
    clickPos.z = Camera.main.transform.position.y - heldObject.position.y;
    Vector3 mousePositionInWorld = Camera.mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(clickPos);

    //You may want to set the position again to clean up floating point errors
    mousePositionInWorld.y = heldObject.position.y;

    return mousePositionInWorld;
}
```